# pig SUM FOREACH GROUP ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i have a set of URLs and associated transaction times in hadoop. i am trying to write a pig script to give me the total transaction time for for each URL.  I am getting a ClassCastException every time I try to SUM the transaction times. first time ive tried pig so any help is appreciated. i can't figure out what im doing wrong.

Here is some output: the urls and transaction times

```
grunt> DESCRIBE uLogUrls
uLogUrls: {url: chararray,et: int}
grunt> DUMP uLogUrls

(/index.jsp,344)
(/another/Access.jsp,517)
(/index.jsp,5)
(/another/NoAccess.jsp,4)
(/index.jsp,5)
(/index.jsp,4)

grps = GROUP uLogUrls BY url;
DUMP grps

(/index.jsp,{(/index.jsp,344),(/index.jsp,5),(/index.jsp,5),(/index.jsp,4)})
(/home/home.jsp,{(/home/home.jsp,11200)})


grunt> DESCRIBE grps
grps: {group: chararray,uLogUrls: {(url: chararray,et: int)}}

total_tx_time = foreach grps generate group as url, SUM(uLogUrls.et);
```

when i execute
    DUMP total_tx_time  i get:

```
    28:05,370 [Thread-44] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map task executor complete.
    2015-09-11 19:28:05,372 [Thread-44] WARN    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1410240575_0002
    java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException:     ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: urlgrp: Local Rearrange[tuple]    {chararray}(false) - scope-73 Operator Key: scope-73):    org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Doubles
        at     org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
    Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:     Exception while executing (Name: urlgrp: Local Rearrange[tuple]{chararray}   (false) - scope-73 Operator Key: scope-73):    org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing    work on Doubles
        at     org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:316)
        at      org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.    POLocalRearrange.getNextTuple(POLocalRearrange.java:291)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine.processOnePackageOutput(PigCombiner.java:197)
    at   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine.reduce(PigCombiner.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine.reduce(PigCombiner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Doubles
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicDoubleMathBase.doTupleWork(AlgebraicDoubleMathBase.java:82)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicDoubleMathBase$Intermediate.exec(AlgebraicDoubleMathBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicDoubleMathBase$Intermediate.exec(AlgebraicDoubleMathBase.java:100)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:323)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextTuple(POUserFunc.java:362)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:361)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:383)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:303)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:307)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicDoubleMathBase.doTupleWork(AlgebraicDoubleMathBase.java:75)
    ... 25 more
```

any ideas what im doing wrong?

thanks!!!

Comment: The grouped alias is grps and in foreach you are iteration over alias : urlgrp ??

Comment: thanks for noticing. i fixed that example. i had ran it twice using a different alias the second time,

Comment: Which version of pig you are using, In my local I tried this use case, using Apache Pig version 0.14.0 and I am able to dump the result. Can you try the example snippet in other version of pig and check once.

Comment: Can you change the data type of et from int to double and run this use case and update on the outcome ?

Comment: i sure will thanks so much!  yes, i also tried that. i should have mentioned. i tried int, double, and float all the same error.  I will try your version of the pig client and post the result. ty again!

Comment: yea getting same problem with pig 0.14.0 ill try again tomorrow. thanks for the help today.

Comment: how does `/home/home.jsp` appear from nowhere and `/another/NoAccess.jsp` disappears just by grouping by `url` ? And also, are there any instances where `et` is blank?

Comment: i was'nt pasting the full dataset GoBrewers as its thousands of URLs...  i will check if there is any case where et is blank, thank you.

Comment: so i tried something else. i tried just a sample file with  just simple dataset like "name <number>" pairs. eg : "abc  123".   then i used the same pattern, and it worked.   one thing i noticed was that when LOAD read my sample data 123 was read as 123.0  using "double". eg. the tuple looks like (abc,123.0).  however, in my above case, after LOAD, I perform a FILTER, then a FOREACH and the tuples have no decimal point.  eg (/index.jsp,344)

Comment: I got it. i wasn't casting properly. in my original FOREACH, i was doing this: 
    uLogUrls = FOREACH uLogs GENERATE urlName as url, runTime as et:double;    when i did (double)runTime as et, then i got tuples with doubles with decimals and it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in the original `FOREACH` to generate uLogUrls I did not cast to double properly.

```
uLogUrls = FOREACH uLogs GENERATE logName as url, runTime as et:double;
```

The above command is what created this exception (notice there are no decimal places for each number).

```
DUMP uLogUrls

(/index.jsp,344)
(/secur/blah.jsp,517)
(/index.jsp,5)
(/secur/blah.jsp,4)
(/index.jsp,5)
....snip....
```

But when I cast it like this:

```
grunt> uLogUrls = FOREACH uLogs GENERATE logName as url, (double)runTime as et;
grunt> DUMP uLogUrls

(/index.jsp,344.0)
(/secur/blah.jsp,517.0)
(/index.jsp,5.0)
(/secur/blah.jsp,4.0)
(/index.jsp,5.0)
...snip....
```

then the `GROUP` and `SUM` functions work.  Thanks for all the help!